# Writing over 1 milion records to csv in python

Tags: python, django, csv

I am extracting some data to a csv file using python, the data is over 1 million records. Definitely there seems to be memory issues with my script because after a painstaking 5 hours and roughly over 190k records written the scripts running process gets killed.

here is my terminal

```
(.venv)[cv1@mdecv01 maidea]$ python common_scripts/script_tests/ben-test-extract.py BEN
Generating CSV file. Please wait ...
Preparing to write file: BEN-data-20170731.csv
Killed
(.venv)[cv1@mdecv01 maidea]$
```

is their a way i can extract this data with proper memory management?

[here](http://www.codesend.com/view/0d97aa0efd61ffa9bc235bf0bc73f2ea/) is my script

Comment: Can you operate anything on `Beneficiary.objects.all()`? Try a print or smth. Else, in case of memory issues in for loop, try to use generators i.e. [yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do#231855)

Comment: maybe posting your code (or a shortened version) _in the question_

Comment: Also include your database setup.

Answer (score 1):

You are not taking advantage of [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) or [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). If you do not use these two methods you will end up performing database calls every time you access a related field (ForeignKey, ManyToManyField)

```
for beneficiary in Beneficiary.objects.all():
    if beneficiary.is_active:
        household = beneficiary.household
        if len(beneficiary.enrolments) > 0 and len(beneficiary.interventions) > 1:
```

Should be something like this

```
for beneficiary in Beneficiary.objects.select_related(
    'household'
).prefetch_related(
    'enrolments',
    'interventions'
):
    if beneficiary.is_active:
        household = beneficiary.household
        if len(beneficiary.enrolments.all()) > 0 and len(beneficiary.interventions.all()) > 1:
```

Answer (score 0):

- Filter in queryset instead of pulling all data for example .filter(is_active=true) , filter by count for example annotate(interventions_count=Count('interventions')).filter(interventions_count__gte=1)
- Pull data in iterations with offset and limit other than pulling it all at once [from (smaller memory consuption) [0:100]
- Make use of select_related and prefetch_related to pre-select tables you need